# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate object to be marshalled in model: {}

Tags: java, spring, exception

After update my spring from **3.1.2.RELEASE** to **4.2.3.RELEASE** and spring-security from **3.1.2.RELEASE** to **3.2.9.RELEASE** I'm having this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate object to be marshalled in model: {}
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView.renderMergedOutputModel(MarshallingView.java:105)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
```

Could someone help me out with what I might be missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you upgrade spring-security to 4.2.3.RELEASE to match your general spring version? Spring usually does not "mash" well between major releases.

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more details here? What controller is being called when this exception occurs? How does the model of response look like? How it is annotated? There is a lot of similar questions and answer depends on details (check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075284/spring-4-jax2bmarshaller-error-when-using-setpackagestoscan) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068628/spring-mvc-jaxb-servletexception-unable-to-locate-object-to-be-marshalled-in) - and pay attention to the level of details provided in those questions)

Comment: Spring and Spring Security have completely different versioning schemes... There is no reason to match those versions...

Comment: @Kostiantyn the controller is default login

Answer (score 0):

I had a look on [Samebug](https://samebug.io/searches/8906654) for you and our users mentioned the following:

> This is a bug in Spring Framework, issue SPR-4518 and it's fixed in
>   v3.0 M3.
>
> jsp-api and servlet-api jars must NOT be deployed by your web app.
>   They should be marked as provided but not deployed by your app.

If that doesn't help, here are a couple of other Stack Overflow questions that may help with this.[MarshallingV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713067/marshallingview-in-spring-mvc-3)[JxBMarshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236662/custom-characterescapehandler-defined-in-jaxbmarshaller-works-in-jetty-but-not)